# Creating Object chain in Quartz Job execution using Google Guice/Dogger in Java Web App

Tags: java, dependency-injection, quartz-scheduler, guice

I started to create a cron job using Quartz in my Java web application to execute one of cleanup task. The actual job is firing as expected and no
problem with the Quatrz job execution. From the below code snippet When I try to use MyService to call the required method as part of job, Dependency is not working.

Object for the MyService class is not created. So I'm getting a null pointer exception. To avoid this I tried to use Google Guice (tried dogger as well) to manage
dependency injection but MyService object creation depends on other classes.

Let's say in this example CustomerService and this CustomerService depends on other classes and those classes depends on some other etc.. So I am going to end up creating object creation chain by using Guice or Dogger.

Code snippet:

```
  import com.google.inject.Inject;
    import com.google.inject.Injector;
    import com.google.inject.Singleton;
    import org.quartz.Job;
    import org.quartz.Scheduler;
    import org.quartz.SchedulerException;
    import org.quartz.spi.JobFactory;
    import org.quartz.spi.TriggerFiredBundle;
    
        @Singleton
        public class CustomJobFactory implements JobFactory {
        
           @Inject
           private Injector injector;
        
           @Override
           public Job newJob(TriggerFiredBundle bundle, Scheduler scheduler) throws SchedulerException {
              return (Job) injector.getInstance(bundle.getJobDetail().getJobClass());
           }
    }


public class QuartzJobHelper  {

   private final Scheduler scheduler;


   @Inject
   public QuartzSchedulerImpl(Scheduler scheduler, CustomJobFactory customJobFactory) {
      this.scheduler = scheduler;
      try {
         this.scheduler.setJobFactory(customJobFactory);
      } catch (SchedulerException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }

   public static void executeJob() throws Exception {

      // The Guice injector used to create instances.
      Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new MyModule());
      JobDetail jobDetail = JobBuilder.newJob(MyJob.class).withIdentity("myjob", "mygroup")
            .build();
    Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().withIdentity("mytrigger", "mygroup")
            .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0/1 * * * * ?")).build();

      SchedulerFactory schedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
      Scheduler scheduler = schedulerFactory.getScheduler();

      // Inform Quartz scheduler to use our factory.
      scheduler.setJobFactory((injector.getInstance(CustomJobFactory.class));
      scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);

      // Start the scheduler.
      scheduler.start();
   }
```

}

import org.quartz.spi.JobFactory;
import java.io.IOException;

```
public class MyModule extends AbstractModule {



   @Override
   protected void configure() {

       bind(JobFactory.class).to(MyJobFactory.class);
       bind(MyService.class).to(MyServiceImpl.class);
       bind(CustomerService.class).to(CustomerServiceImpl.class);
       bind(MyDao.class).to(MyDaoImpl.class);
       bind(CustomCache.class).to(CustomCacheImpl.class);
       bind(ProxyDao.class).to(ProxyDaoImpl.class);
       bind(RequestDao.class).to(DefaultRequestDao.class);
       |
       |
       |
       etc.. Likewise so many dependencies are there to inject but finding 100's of dependencies.
     
   }

}

public class MyJob extends org.quartz.Job {

 @Inject
 MyService service;

 public void execute(JobExecutionContext jobContext) throws JobExecutionException {
      service.cleanupJunkData();
     }    
}

class MyService {
 void cleanupJunkData();
}

@Named
class MyServiceImpl implments MyService {
   
   private CustomerService cs; 
   private MyDao dao;
   private CustomCache cache;
   
   @Inject 
   public MyServiceImpl(CustomerService cs, MyDao dao, CustomCache cache) {
     this.cs = cs;
     this.dao=dao;
     this.cache = cache;
   }
   
   @Override
   public void cleanupJunkData() {
     List<Customer> customerData = cs.getCustomerData(dao.getExpiredCustId());
     cache.clear(customerData);
   }
}

public Class MainClass {
  public static void main(Stirng[] args) {
      QuartzJobHelper.executeJob();
  }
}
```

Could someone suggest how to deal with object creation in Quartz job?

Comment: In your updated code, which of the `@Inject` is null?  Your module looks good.  Your job and service look good.  It looks like you're setting the `jobFactory` through the Injector.  Just need to know which ones are null still in order to help.

Comment: Thank you for reply @kendavidson. I am not getting null for any inject  but If you see my module which has lot of bind() to create the objects. I have to do lot of bind()s because of so many dependencies and its not going to end. see etc.. in MyModule and has so many other dependencies to bind() and guice is keep on giving error to inject all the deps(No Implemention) but It seems there is no end in that because I have to do many objects(not sure how many) to be cretaed for one object creation. Is there any better way to deal with this case.

Comment: No. There are going to be a ton of binds.  We break our modules up by feature. So each feature has like 50+ binds. And we have like 10 modules. But as long as they are installed jnto the injector, it'll just work, like magic.  I'd need to see all the code to debug a no implementionnerror though.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't provided any Guice specific code in your example, but you want to create a `JobFactory`, which will be responsible for injecting each job as they are fired:

```java
public class GuiceJobFactory implements JobFactory {
    @Inject
    private Injector guiceInjector;
    
    @Override
    public Job newJob(TriggerFiredBundle bundle, Scheduler scheduler) throws SchedulerException {
        return (Job) guiceInjector.getInstance(bundle.getJobDetail().getJobClass());
    }
}
```

You can create this however you choose, but you'll need to somehow get the `Injector` into it.

**Edit**

From your comment, I don't really understand.  We have the following setup (with multiple jobs):

```java
JobThatDoesSomething:
@Inject Service1 service1;

Service1:
@Inject Dao1 dao1;
@Inject Dao2 dao2;
@Inject ValidationFactory validationFactory;

ValidationFactory:
@Inject ValidationProvider provider;
```

This is at a high level the hierarchy of just a single job.  We have about 100 that have the same level of injected dependencies.  From what I can tell, this is exactly the same as you?

What are you saying?  That with this factory your:

- MyService is not injected?
- MyService.CustomerService is not injected?
- Etc?

**Edit 2**

You need to create your injector somehow.  I've added your main code, with an example of how you would use your `CustomModule` and `JobFactory`:

```java
public Class MainClass {
  public static void main(Stirng[] args) {
       // You need to create your injector here
       Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new CustomModule());

       SchedulerFactory schedFact = new org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory();
        Scheduler scheduler = schedFact.getScheduler();
        scheduler.setJobFactory(new GuiceJobFactory(injector));  // Use it here
        scheduler.start();
         
        // define the job and tie it to our HelloJob class
        JobBuilder jobBuilder = JobBuilder.newJob(MyJob.class);
        JobDataMap data = new JobDataMap();
        data.put("latch", this);
         
        JobDetail jobDetail = jobBuilder.usingJobData("example", "com.QuartzSchedulerExample") 
                .usingJobData(data)
                .withIdentity("myJob", "group1")
                .build();
         
         
        // Fire at curent time + 1 min every day
        Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
        .withIdentity("myTrigger", "group1")
        .startAt(DateBuilder.todayAt(10, 20, 20))
        .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0 " + (min + 1) + " " + hour + " * * ? *"))     
        .build();
         
        // Tell quartz to schedule the job using our trigger
        scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have only one job and I have used this job factory but to run that job lot of other nested dependencies are required as I pointed out MyService Object.

Comment: I don't understand?  If you have all of your dependencies bound correctly in the module, then get the Injector from that module, Injecting the instance of the Job Class, will hierarchically inject all the dependencies.

Comment: We have about 100 that have the same level of injected dependencies- Yes same problem we have exactly here. I tried to inject MyService and which depends on  CustomerService and so on(using Guice - bind API).. It became like big chain but it is n ot ending. Do we have any better approach to deal with this kind of chain?

Comment: We have that DI existed with big chain but when we try to use @Inject MyService service, Quartz is not accepting DI that's the reason started using Guice.

Comment: Again, I'm really sorry. I don't understand your problem.  Using everything from my example, all dependencies are being injected properly.  Like I said before, in your `main` there is absolutely no Guice code, so I can't tell whether you're doing that properly.  How do you expect things to be injected, if you're not building the Guice injector?  Can you post that code?

Comment: Sorry for not providing full details. I have updated my post with guice related code.

Comment: I have updated the question with Guice related code now. Please check the updated post once